# QTP identification property developer name in JAVA SWT

Tags: java, swt, qtp

I have a Problem with a special identification Property in JAVA SWT (Eclipse). In QTP exist the identification Property 'developer name' which will be set in JAVA.

### Example:

```
control.setData("myControl") //this will be resolved by QTP as developer name
control.setData("developer name", "myControl") //in this case, QTP does NOT identify the property.
```

Ich have had already opened a support ticket at HP but the answer was confusing me. They said that `setData(String key, Object value)` and `setData(Object data)` should work but we experienced that `setData(String key, Object data)` does not work! Our developers must not use `setData(Object data)` because this Method is prohibited by the Architecture-Board for reason of DataBinding.

Does somebody know another way to set the 'developer name' Property?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? Facing a similar problem.

Comment: Hi Baz, no until now we don't find a solution.